# Django - displaying images on the page using pyuploadcare

Tags: python, django, html, image, uploadcare

Python, Django, pyuploadcare, html5, jquery,
The Django documentations for pyuploadcare are useful for image customization and file uploading and stuff like that, but what they don't tell you is how to display the image in the webpage. For example, i can display the URL where the image is stored, but i cannot display the image itself in the webpage
i want to make this as clear as possible to the reader so I'll give another example:
To build an image gallery, i would need all the images displayed on one page, i can do that using the for loops

```
for photo in photos
```

Photo and photos are defined in views.py

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% for photo in photos %}


{{ photo.caption }}
{{ photo.photo }}

{% endfor %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

photo.caption is an `models.CharField()`
photo.photo is an `ImageField()` from

```
from pyuploadcare.dj.models import ImageField
```

everything is working properly but i don't know how to display the images on the webpage.
Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple
`<img src="{{ photo.photo }}" />` should be enough, as ImageField just holds the CDN URL value.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked    
<img src="{{ photo.photo }}" class="responsive-img">